# functional scope and "this" in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, this

I have this simple bit of code (where ko == knockout lib):

```
$(function() {
    //var el = document.getElementById('foo');
    //console.log(el);
    $("#foo").click (function() {console.log(this);});
         }); // this == $("#foo")

    ko.computed(function () {
        console.log('ko computed',this); // this == window object
    });
});
```

Why is "this" not bound to "ko" in the callback? I would expect it to be bound to the calling function, as in the click handler.

Comment: aren't you doing `ko.applyBindings(// vm function)`  which is the starting point .

Comment: No, in this example I am just creating a computed observable, which executes the callback function when it is created. Calling applyBindings shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: `ko.computed(function () {
        console.log('ko computed',this);
    }.bind(this));`???

Comment: this is because ko is executed on page and context of `this` is set to window. if you want to have different `this` you can use 'bind' function method

Comment: How is it different from the click handler?

Comment: The binding you get in jQuery callbacks is deliberately done by that library; there's nothing automatic about it.  Knockout clearly wasn't designed with the same ideas.

Comment: in `click` `this` is set by `jQuery` the same way (via `bind`, or `call` or `apply`)

Comment: may be this at the end `},this)` here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27497/

Comment: @Pointy - to clarify, jQuery is explicitly binding the function to the DOM element in the source?

Comment: The context of a callback is set (or not set) by the function that calls the callback. In both of the above cases, that's controlled by the code of the library. If the library doesn't call the callback with a context, it's context will be `window` or `undefined` depending on whether or not you are in strict mode. In the jQuery example, jQuery is using something similar to `callback.call(thejQueryinstance,normalizedEventObject)`

Comment: @MusicalShore jQuery is explicitly doing something internally to guarantee that the DOM element is bound to `this` when the handler is called, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the [knockout.js sourcecode](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/158e45f20bdb57b68b273cb9fe699f509614d650/src/subscribables/dependentObservable.js#L305) for this method we find this line:

```js
return state.evaluatorFunctionTarget ? readFunction.call(state.evaluatorFunctionTarget) : readFunction();
```

If no evaluatorFunctionTarget is supplied (the second argument in `ko.computed`) the callback gets called with no context and `this` will be the default `window` context.

If you passed a second argument, the callback is called with `this` being whatever you passed.

Unless a function is called as a property of another object ( `someobject.someMethod()` ), is called with `.call()` or `.apply()`, or has a context bound to it with `.bind()`, then `this` will always be the `window` object.

Comment: So jQuery is explicitly binding the callback to the DOM element internally?

Comment: Yes, jQuery's event handler functions add this binding manually.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `computed` is the context, e.g.

```
ko.computed(function () {
    console.log('ko computed',this);
}, this);
```

Or you can explicitly bind to `ko`.

```
ko.computed(function () {
    console.log('ko computed',this);
}, ko);
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html